# dragging data from editText to other editText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am implementing Excel for android devices and I am printing EditTexts using baseAdapter and I want to drag data from one EditText to another how can i do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the EditTexts you have in a relative layout, then implement the EditText on touch listener.
When a user press the EditText create a TextView with the text from EditText, then make drag and drop on the TextView, and if the TextView is being dropped inside another EditText, put the text there.

Comment: Yes i understand the way but how can we implement a listener on second EditText that a drop is happened or its touched firstTime

Comment: When you release the TextView, (Action - up), you need if the TextView is currently located in the EditText area (a little dirty works with margins, but that's the way you got to do it) and if it does, copy the TextView's text to this EditText.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create TextView onLongTouch of EditText, change its position according to the swipe and if last coordinates of swipe are the coordinates of EditText Copy text of TextView in it

Answer (score 0):

Ues below code and it will work fine.

Just drag your textview to any editbox and it will show exact value in edit box.
Just take 2 - 3 textview and 2 - 3 edittext and put anywhere on screen then follow below code.
Below is code.

```
  textViewObject.setOnTouchListener(this);


   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent)
   {
    TextView tvResult = (TextView) view;
    String strData = tvResult.getText().toString();
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
         ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("text", strData);
         DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
         view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```